# Redirect one URL to another on the same site trick?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, virtualhost

what I want to achive

prod.com to be immediately moved to prod.com/cms

when I did Redirect permanent / /cms

I got a lot of /cmscmscmscmscms etc. Any ideas?

my vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName prod.com
     DocumentRoot /home/www/sites/prod/html/development
     <Directory /home/www/sites/prod/html/development>
            AllowOverride All
     </Directory>

     SSLEngine on
     SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle.crt
     SSLCertificateFile    /etc/pki/tls/certs/prod.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/prod.key

     <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
     </FilesMatch>

     BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
     nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
     downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
     BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
```

my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/API [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /Application/API/api.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$  /Application/controller.php [L]

DirectoryIndex /Application/controller.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you got a redirect loop was because `Redirect / /cms` matches any path starting with / and appends the old path onto the new path. What you actually want is:

```
RedirectMatch ^\/$ /cms
```

This only matches /